# Drupal 7 webform output in excel

Tags: drupal, export-to-excel, drupal-webform

I look for a solution for my client:

Problem:
At this moment people can download on a website an excel file, they put information in and send the excel file back by email to the company. A shorter way would be using a webform, less steps for the visitor - possibility to check if all the information is put in (correctly) - possibility to give information about the data that the visitor has to put in.

Installing/working with webforms i can.

But the information received by the company need to be in a excel file, because a other computerprogram import this information and can only read a excel file.

Question:

Which solution do you see for my problem. I want to offer my client a solution so at the end he will receive and excel file like they do right now. His website will be a drupal 7 with the webform installed.
Is there a possibility to output the information from a filled in webform in a excell file?

Any tips/links are welcome!
If there is a freelancer that can do this job, they may also contact me.

Thanks for reading and answers/tips/suggestions.

Kristof
kristof@firstthings.be

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) on your custom created form submit process.

- Use hook_form_alter for your webform
- Add your custom function to **#submit** array
- Use PHPExcel